# How to Autostart an AlarmManager to start a Scheduled Activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, alarm, autostart

This tutorial come from [android-er](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-alarmmanager-to-start-scheduled.html),
The main activity(AndroidScheduledActivity.java) start a AlarmManager to trigger BroadcastReceiver(MyScheduledReceiver.java) repeatly. In the onReceive() method of MyScheduledReceiver, it start another activity(MyScheduledActivity.java) indirectly. Such that the activity(MyScheduledActivity.java) will be start in scheduled interval.
Now I would use AutoStart to start automatically, but I was not able to write the AutoStartNotifyReceiver .
please can you give me an idea how to manage it ?
Thanks a LOT !

main activity, AndroidScheduledActivity.java :

```
public class AndroidScheduledActivity extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
      buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
      MyScheduledReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent
     = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
       0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager
      = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    long interval = 60 * 1000; //
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
      calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    finish();
  }});
  }

}
```

Then BroadcastReceiver, MyScheduledReceiver.java

```
public class MyScheduledReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledActivity.class);
 scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
}
}
```

and my problem AutoStartNotifyReceiver :

```
public class AutoStartNotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  if(intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)){

????????????????????

  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `AutoStartNotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` class is there because the alarms get cleared when the device resets. So, in the `onReceive` of this class (where you have the question marks) you need to set the alarm all over again with the same code (without, of course the `finish()`)that you used to do it the first time in the `onClick` method of `AndroidScheduledActivity`.

Then, you need to put the following entry in your `Manifest` to let the system know to launch your `AutoStartNotifyReceiver` when the system boots up:

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoStartNotifyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As well as a permission in the `Manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Now, this is all assuming you only have one alarm and only set it one way every time. If that is not the case than this gets a bit more complicated. But based on the little info you provided, my solution should do what you want.

Also, since you are a newcomer here just a kindly reminder: when someone provides an adequate answer to a question, the person asking the question (you) accepts the answer by clicking the checkbox next to the answer. This is so the person answering gets credit. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

thanks, it works. just need to improve my java a little more. I have to add "context" don t  know exactly why.

```
public class AutoStartNotifyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION)){

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledReceiver.class);
             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, myIntent, 0);

             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
             calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
             long interval = 60 * 1000;
             alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);           
        }
    }
}
```